# Connect Android device to web service on Laptop

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

In my house I can connect my android device to the service in my laptop as they are both on the same network. My question is, supossing I'm going to a bar and I can connect my laptop to the wifi but not the cellphone, how can I make the cellphone reach the web service on the laptop?
   I tried to create an add hoc network and connectify.me but neither worked. With Connectify.me I was  able to connect to the laptop from the phone but the phone could reach the web service (maybe a filter for the free version?)
   Any advice?
   I've already checked this: [Connect an Android Device To a Web Service on Local Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176609/connect-an-android-device-to-a-web-service-on-local-host) and it's not the same as my problem.
   Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried *Connectify*, but [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) worked for me. There are some more instructions [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-share-internet-connection-between-pc-and-android-phone-using-wifi/) if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, supossing I'm going to a bar and I can connect my laptop to the wifi but not the cellphone, how can I make the cellphone reach the web service on the laptop?

Most likely, you can't. The bar is unlikely to have given you a public IP address, and it unlikely that you will convince the bartender to allow you to modify their firewall to forward a port to your notebook.