# Debug android app that connects to local PC service over USB on OSX

Tags: android, macos, networking

I'm going to fly out of state tomorrow, and it'd be ideal if I was able to continue working on my Android app while I'm in the air.

The problem is, my app requires a backend service that I can run on my laptop (OSX). At home this is simple, because I'm on my local WiFi network and I can simply connect to a box with the service hosted on it, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to debug the app over USB only.

I'd really much prefer to not share a local WiFi network through my laptop due to battery usage - it'd be best if I could leverage the USB connection I already have to debug and create a local network between my phone and my laptop.

I've seen [a few other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539795/949286) that mention I should be able to select the USB Tether option, but when I tried it, it first attempts to contact my provider (Verizon) to see if the feature is available. When I put the phone into airplane mode, it's unable to communicate with my carrier, so it doesn't look like this will be possible in the air. Regardless, it doesn't seem to work out of the box on OSX.

In reality, my local service situation is a bit more complex than average (it actually runs in a VM). The ideal situation would be to create a local network between my computer and my device, so it can access all VMs (Vagrant/VirtualBox) within the network.

If I'm reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747152/connect-android-device-to-web-service-on-laptop) correctly, it looks like [there may be other solutions for Windows](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/), but I'd really rather run it in OSX if that's possible.

How can I create a local network between my laptop and Android device over USB?

Comment: You might get somewhere with an adb forward and an inbound ssh connection from the mac to the phone setting up a tunnel usable in the reverse direction.  But is it really worth the effort?  Can you work on an emulator during the flight?

Comment: @pnuts - "networking" is an appropriate tag in this case, as it concerns network connections in the *unique* context of supporting development, not network programming, and not general usage.  Development tools are explicitly on-topic here.

Comment: It may not be appropriate in other cases, but it is fully logical and appropriate in this one.  Read and take time to understand before you act!

Comment: Read and take time to understand the **question** - don't just blindly vandalize.