# Android device won't connect to local server

Tags: android, localhost, wamp

I made an app that connects to a php file. The code is working using the AVD without a problem. Now when I tried the app in my android device it force closes. My android device is connected through a wifi network. I'm using wamp server on windows 7.

I have pinpointed the problem but I cannot resolve it. I'm hoping one of you good guys can help me.
This is my culprit (192.168.1.100 is the machines IP):

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.100/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

How can this be solved? 100% working in AVD but won't work in actual android device.

Comment: what android version is avd and what the actual device?

Comment: Can you put the stack trace?

Comment: What happens if you type that address into your device's default browser?

Comment: Try to open your url on device browser,check if is it working ? If its not working there, means your device is unable to connect to your local machine using wifi

Comment: @user1527232 it's on API 17

Comment: @NickT Browsers tells me it is forbidden

Comment: @hardcoded where is stack trace found?

Comment: @droidH it is in your logcat of your eclipse.

Comment: @hardcoded all I found is:
03-15 12:06:26.824: W/Trace(734): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Answer (score 1):

@droidH  if you working on local server change your url to 10.0.2.2 to your IP address

go to this link it works
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I already tried that. To no avail.
I've also been here:
[link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check two things :

- Your external IP address i.e if you are using windows use command
  "ipconfig" and get IPv4 address.
- Check you permissions in AndroidManifest :

> ```
> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
> ```

Also check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510143/644011

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- first, put both your android device and your computer into the same network as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176609/connect-an-android-device-to-a-web-service-on-local-host/8666128#comment33616171_8666128)
- then, make your device connect directly to your computer via its IP in that network (find the IP as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/16510143#16510143))

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to connect your mobile to the same network as your computer.
   I used virtual router to make my mobile in same network as my laptop
2. Then use ip address of your computer to access your computer web server from your mobile.