# Calling web service from android device

Tags: android, web-services, android-webservice

I have written a web service locally using python flask framework which runs on `localhost:5000` , I run this web service successfully from my computers browser by writing `http://localhost:5000/toi/something`

Now I am trying to call same service from the browser of my android device by connecting it with the machine.
I am doing this for the first time so I am not sure whether it works this way or I am doing something wrong but it does not show me the output on my android device.
Once this is done I will be calling the web service programatically in my android application.

Thank You
[image: ifconfig image]
[image: ip for which I am getting expected result on machine]
[image: ip for which I am not getting result on machine] 
[image: android device using 1st IP]
[image: android device using 2nd IP]

Comment: In place of local host put your machine ip address

Comment: @user88 already tried that...but it doesn't show me anything ....as not even page not found error...just keeps on loading...

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that will work, if you´ve got the phone connected to the same Wifi network than your computer you should access it this way:

```
http://ipofyourcomputer:5000/toi/something/
```

Once this works out you can try it with some of the libraries available on Android like:

> OkHttp - https://github.com/square/okhttp
>
> android-async-http - http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
>
> Volley - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley

Or if you're building a **REST** service you can use:

> Retrofit - http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Hope it helps.

Comment: is WIFI compulsory..? I have connected device using USB in teathering mode...? Should it not work..?

Comment: Wifi it´s just a scenario, if device and pc are connected to same Wifi network for example, the router will give both different IP address so localhost stands for the IP of each one. ie: android ip (1.1.1.1) and pc ip (2.2.2.2) localhost:5000/toi/something will resolve to 1.1.1.1:5000/toi/something and not 2.2.2.2:5000/toi/something

Comment: In your case I think that if the mobile works as a router this one will have a different IP from the PC. That's because for the inner network that your mobile creates, every device connected should have different IP.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot call the web service just by connecting the device to my machine using USB I need to have them over same WIFI network..?

Comment: Nope, that means you cannot call localhost:5000/toi/something on your mobile and get to your computer. You will have to use ipconfig (windows) or ifconfig (Mac/Linux) on your computer and make the call from you Android browser to http://thatip:5000/toi/something

Comment: @y.dixit were you able to access your app?

Comment: I tried connecting android device to machine using USB teathering and then tried to access the web service using, `192.168.42.154:5000/toi/input parameters` but I get `could not connect to error 192.168.42.154:5000` .....I later even tried using localhost:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5000 (both are actually same)...but that also dint work....

Comment: I even found the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176609/connect-an-android-device-to-a-web-service-on-local-host) and tried soln given by Zulkifli fasilkom01 but even that dint worked for me....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47926/discussion-between-axierjhtjz-and-y-dixit)

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by turning off windows firewall.

Comment: You have 50 poit you can make a comment, this can be a comment not an answer!