# Displaying radio buttons based on count

Tags: android, web-services

I want to display the radio buttons dynamicaly based on count but I am unable to display.

This is my source code

```
  public class PeriodChange extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  /**
   * Called when the activity is first created.
  */
  int count=0;
  Button btnSubmitBarcode;
EditText txtPhelebotomistid, txtBarcode;
RadioGroup rad;

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    invokeWS();
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);


}

public void invokeWS(){

     // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
     client.get("http://192.168.10.8:8080/useraccount/barcode/periodcount",new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
         // When the response returned by REST has Http response code '200'
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(String response) {
             addRadioButtons(response);
         }
         // When the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
         @Override
         public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
             String content) {
             PeriodChange m=new PeriodChange();
          // When Http response code is '404'
             if(statusCode == 404){
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 m.showMessage("not found","Requested resource not found");
             } 
             // When Http response code is '500'
             else if(statusCode == 500){
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 m.showMessage("wrong","Something went wrong at server end");
             } 
             // When Http response code other than 404, 500
             else{
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 m.showMessage("error","Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]");
             }
         }
     });

}

public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public void addRadioButtons(String response){
    int x=Integer.parseInt(response);


    RadioGroup rgp= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;
   // System.out.println("count1---X---"+x);
    Log.d("count","count");

    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
          RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
          radioButton.setText("period"+i);
          radioButton.setId(i);
          rprms= new        RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);          
          rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms);
    }

}   
}
```

Following is XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >                    

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The following is Logcat

```
12-11 09:59:18.860: W/KeyCharacterMap(275): No keyboard for id 0
12-11 09:59:18.860: W/KeyCharacterMap(275): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-11 09:59:28.559: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6569 objects / 321184 bytes in 76ms
12-11 09:59:39.879: W/System.err(275): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
12-11 09:59:39.889: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:564)
12-11 09:59:39.889: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:88)
12-11 09:59:39.899: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
12-11 09:59:39.899: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
12-11 09:59:39.899: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
12-11 09:59:39.909: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
12-11 09:59:39.909: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
12-11 09:59:39.909: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
12-11 09:59:39.909: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
12-11 09:59:39.909: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
12-11 09:59:39.919: W/System.err(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:564)
12-11 09:59:39.929: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:88)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
12-11 09:59:39.939: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-11 09:59:39.949: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-11 09:59:39.959: W/System.err(275):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-11 09:59:39.959: W/System.err(275):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-11 09:59:39.959: D/AndroidRuntime(275): Shutting down VM
12-11 09:59:39.959: W/dalvikvm(275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:743)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:273)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.mkyong.android.PeriodChange.showMessage(PeriodChange.java:154)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.mkyong.android.PeriodChange$2.onFailure(PeriodChange.java:146)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onFailure(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:301)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onFailure(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:315)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:373)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:135)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-11 09:59:39.979: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 10:04:40.040: I/Process(275): Sending signal. PID: 275 SIG: 9
```

this is the method I am calling from webservice

```
@GET
// Path: http://localhost/<appln-folder-name>/login/dologin
@Path("/periodcount")
// Produces JSON as response
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String getNumberOfPeriods(){

    String response = "";
    try
    {
    DBConnection db=new DBConnection();
    System.out.println("s1");
    int studyID=DBConnection.getStudyId();
    System.out.println(studyID);
    //System.out.println("s2");

    response = String.valueOf(DBConnection.getPeriods(studyID));
    //System.out.println(studieslist);
    //System.out.println("s3");
    //Gson gson = new Gson();
    //System.out.println("s4");
    //System.out.println(gson.toJson(studieslist));
    //System.out.println("s5");
    //response = gson.toJson(studieslist);
    //System.out.println("s6");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Exception Error"); //Console 
    }
    return response;
    }
```

this is getStudyId() method

```
public static int getStudyId() throws Exception {
    boolean isUserAvailable = false;

    Connection dbConn = null;
    try {
        try {
            dbConn = DBConnection.createConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(employeeId);
        Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(employeeId);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM active_study_details WHERE emp_id = '" + employeeId+"'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(employeeId);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("eid.....dddd......"+rs.getInt("study_id"));
            studyID=rs.getInt("study_id");
            System.out.println(studyID);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
    }
    return studyID;
}
```

this is getPeriods(int studyID) method

```
 public static int getPeriods(int studyID) throws Exception {
    boolean isUserAvailable = false;
    int count=0;

    Connection dbConn = null;
    try {
        try {
            dbConn = DBConnection.createConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(studyID);
        Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(studyID);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM study_period WHERE study_id = '" + studyID+"'";
        //String query = "SELECT * FROM active_study_details WHERE emp_id = '" + employeeId+"'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(studyID);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println("eid.....dddd......"+rs.getInt("study_id"));
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
            //System.out.println(studyID);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);

    return count;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: call method invokeWS(); after setcontentview...not before

Comment: @ Hetal Upadhyay I did as you said but I am getting same error

Comment: i think now it is error of your network connection...do one thing..to check your radio button working...just call that method without network connection...just for checking

Comment: @Hetal Upadhyay yes I just called that method without network connection. Now radio buttons are displaying. But how to solve network connection error.

Comment: post your full network code...what are you using for it...have you given internet permission in menifest?

Comment: @Hetal Upadhyay I have posted network code please check it. I have given internet permission in menifest

Comment: are you testing on emulator or real device? because localhost will not work with real device....and in emulator check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176609/connect-an-android-device-to-a-web-service-on-local-host

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code** :-

```
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){
      RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
      radioButton.setText("period"+i);
      radioButton.setId(i*2 + 1);
      rprms= new        RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);          
      rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms);
}
```

**UPDATE:->**

add below lines to your oncreated instead of your method:-

```
 RadioGroup rgp= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
```