# How to Access ASP.NET Localhost Website on Android Mobile

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, mobile, localhost

**How to Access ASP.NET Localhost Website on Android Mobile**

I am trying to access Asp.net Localhost Website on Android but nothing show on my Android Mobile. I am using same wifi on my laptop and Android Mobile but nothing show on Android Mobile. Please Help me.

Comment: can you add some code? What have you tried so far? May be articles you read or tutorials?

Comment: Are you debugging using an emulator or in device mode? [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176609/connect-an-android-device-to-a-web-service-on-local-host) might help

Answer (score 0):

How you are connecting ASP.net website through android Device? through code or browser? have you host that website on IIS? have you allow firewall on particular port etc? Can't say anything without full detail.