# android retrofit library using example works fine in emulator but not in any mobile why?

Tags: android, mobile

I tried to run my retrofit library using example to store data into local server and run from emulator then its works fine but when i run from my mobile then give some error. my question is that how do i run this from my mobile and which kind of ip address i use ?

public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080";
and also giving error from,
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

with emulator it works but not from any mobile, mobile is supportable and its api level is kitkat and more.

Comment: post your posting code using retrofit

Comment: if you are running in real device try it with "http://your_local_server_machine_ip:8080"

Comment: after changing my port number i fnd this error:     retrofit.RetrofitError.failed to connect to / "my_server_machine_ip" (port 8080) after 15000ms

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17603378/1790537 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/36645473/1790537 make sure your device and server machine are connected via usb.

Comment: i tried with volley also there timeout error comes but used system ip address also tell me how to over come to this problem

Answer (score 3):

After waste my hours, I find this code

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

add this code to your Manifest.xml between application tags.

Answer (score 0):

You use your computer IP address on real device for example your computer has Ip address of 192.168.0.101:8080 use that url in your root url.

it works on emulator because your emulator is running inside the same computer and 127.0.0.1:8080 is your localhost.

please make sure your computer and your device have same Network i.e same wifi router.

Comment: I tried a lot,I used my system ip address,in same network in different different mobile but not working ,is there any problem with firewall or some  solution plz share