# failure connecting to server host

Tags: android, mysql, server

my app is unable to connect to my MySQL database. when I run the app on my device and try to register an account after a while, it returns an error "failed to connect to /192.168.44.135(port 443) after 10000ms". please I want to know what could result to this error,

I need a clue on how to solve it.

Comment: check if your device can access your server via its IP address and port (IP:port) from the web browser. Probably the server IP has changed? Worth a try :) Goodluck!

Comment: i checked it by running `ipconfig` command in my system cmd and it's still same thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect an Android Device To a Web Service on Local Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176609/connect-an-android-device-to-a-web-service-on-local-host)

Answer (score 0):

mysql enable remote access...

```
** GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**
```

Comment: i ran the code in mysql console and it returned an error

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'
```

1. dbname: your database name.
2. dbuser: ex. root, vmusr

and view in /mysqlaccess.conf

```
# ----------------#
# Global settings #
# --------------- #
  #$Param{'host'}     = '';
  $Param{'user'}     = 'nobody';
  $Param{'db'}       = 'test';
  $Param{'password'} = 'foobar';
  $Param{'debug'}    = 0;

# --------------------------#
# Settings for Command-line #
# ------------------------- #
if ($CMD) {
  $Param{'superuser'} = 'root';
  $Param{'rhost'}     = 'localhost';
  $Param{'spassword'} = '';
  $Param{'brief'}     = 1;
}
```

or set in mysql-shell:

```
$ mysql -u root -p yourpass
```

after login:

```
shell> mysql --host=remote.example.com --port=13306
```